# What are the default arguments for ClutterGst?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3, gstreamer

Hello everyone I am trying to make a simple video player using `Gtk3 python` & `Gstreamer`. I am also using `Clutter`,`ClutterGtk` & `ClutterGst`

The problem arises when initialise the ClutterGst like:

```
ClutterGst.init()
```

but I dont know the argument which should be passed here. If I try `sys.argv` my Gtk window disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You start by initializing ClutterGtk, then GstClutter, both with sys.argv, then everything should work fine.

Take a look at audience's initialization code for example:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~audience-members/audience/trunk/view/head:/Audience/Audience.vala#L898
(not sure if the X.init_threads is really necessary, but there were some strange problems in Audience which were (probably) solved with this)